# prove that $\sin (\tan x)\geq x\;\forall x\in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right]$

Tags: calculus

> Using the relation $2(1-\cos x)<x^2,x\neq 0$ or otherwise, prove that
>   $$
> \sin (\tan x)\geq x\;\forall x\in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right]
> $$

**My Attempt:**

Let $f(x) = \sin (\tan x)-x$. Then $f'(x) = \cos (\tan x)\cdot \sec^2 x-1$. Now using the given statement that $2(1-\cos x)<x^2$ for $x\neq0$, set $x=\tan x$ to get

$$
\begin{align}
2(1-\cos (\tan x))&<\tan^2 x\\
\left[1-\cos (\tan x)\right]&<\frac{\tan^2 x}{2}\\
\cos (\tan x)&>\left[\frac{2-\tan^2 x}{2}\right]\\
\cos (\tan x)\cdot \sec^2 x-1&>\left[\frac{2-\tan^2 x}{2}\right]\cdot \sec^2 x-1\\
f'(x)&>\left[\frac{2-\tan^2 x}{2}\right]\cdot \sec^2 x-1\\
f'(x)&>\tan^2 x-\frac{\tan^2 x}{2}\cdot \sec^2 x\\
f'(x) \color{red}{=} \frac{\tan^2 x}{2}\cdot \left[2-\sec^2 x\right]&>0\;\; \forall x\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\
f'(x)&>0\;\; \forall x\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Thus $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function for $x\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$. Furthermore,

$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&>f(0)\\
\sin (\tan x)-x&\geq 0\\
\sin (\tan x)-x&>0 \;\forall x\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Now $f(0)=0$ and $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \sin (1)-\frac{\pi}{4}>0$. Therefore,

$$
f(x)\geq 0\;\forall x \in  \left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right]
$$

Can we solve this using any other method?

Comment: Probably simpler to set $u = \tan x$, then you need to show $\sin u \geqslant \arctan u$ for $0 \leqslant u \leqslant 1$. $$\sin u - \arctan u = \int_0^u \cos t - \frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt,$$ so $\cos t \geqslant 1 - \frac{t^2}{2} \geqslant \frac{1}{1+t^2}$ ends it.

Comment: you doing well..

Comment: Thanks  Daniel Fischer, Thanks  mwomath.

Comment: In the first quadrant, actually the inequality is true up to $\theta = 1 \approx 57^{\circ}$

Comment: If you consider the terms of the Taylor series of $\tan$ and $\arcsin$, then you essentially want to prove that $$\frac{2^{3n-1}(2^{2n}-1)B_n}{(2n)!}\ge\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k-1)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}k}$$ where $B_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers.